# Increment Button at Javascript using html and css. I am bit confused

Tags: javascript, html, css

Neither in the IDE when I preview does the button click nor in the various browsers I used. (Mozilla, Chrome)

I want the button to click but I can not do it although the IDE does not get an error. Take the following piece of code:

```js
function increment() {
  console.log("The button was clicked")
}
increment()
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#increment-btn {
  background: darkred
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="el">

<head>
  <title>Page Count</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>People enter:</h1>
  <h2 id="count">100</h2>
  <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"but I can not do it"* - Can you clarify what you mean by that?  What specific indication of a problem are you observing?

Comment: It seems to work just fine. I have edited your question so you can directly execute the code. Everytime the button is clicked *"The button was clicked"* is logged to the console. What else do you expect to happen?

Comment: @DinhCarabus the point is that button not clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Javascript file don't call the function again. as you are already calling it on button,

i mean on button you have added " onclick " handler it should work just fine. just remove last line in Javascript file